# Why is a template being looked in a theme and not in my module?

Tags: theming, 8

I have created a custom module. in that module I have create a custom twig template using `hook_theme` function

```
function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'mymodule_settings' => array(
      'variables' => array(
        'role' => NULL,
      )
    )
  );
}
```

Then I created a custom block using my module here is the code of the block

```
public function build() {
    $config = \Drupal::config('mymodule.config');
    $role = $config->get('role');
    return array(
      '#theme' => 'mymodule_settings',
      '#role' => $role,
    );
  }
```

I created a templates directory in my module and inside that directory I have created `mymodule-settings.html.twig` file.

Cleared the cache but Drupal gives me the following error.

```
Twig_Error_Loader: Template "themes/subtheme/templates/mymodule-settings.html.twig" is not defined (Drupal\Core\Template\Loader\ThemeRegistryLoader: Unable to find template "themes/subtheme/templates/mymodule-settings.html.twig" in the Drupal theme registry.). in Twig_Loader_Chain->getCacheKey() (line 45 of themes/basetheme/templates/block.html.twig).
```

My theme is a subtheme. Why Drupal is looking for the template in the theme and not in my module?

Comment: This should be working, are you sure it is nog a typo in the hook_theme name? Cleared cache?

Comment: The problem was, I was using the same name for custom module and my subtheme. Should I delete the question?

Answer (score -1):

Try like this:

```
function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'mymodule_settings' => array(
      'variables' => array(
        'role' => NULL,
      )
      'template' => 'mymodule-settings',
    )
  );
}
```

You are missing to define template.

Comment: Template doesn't have to be defined, when omitted it searches for mymodule-settings.html.twig by default.

Comment: I think it searches by default in theme template folder, not module folder. I am not specific on this but for my case it happened and I defined template in hook_theme().